# WIndows SourceTree で コードの一部を検索する方法はありますか？

Tags: git, sourcetree

WIndows版のSourceTreeで変更履歴を記録しています。
気がついたら、定数の定義を削除してしまったようです。

しかし、それがどのタイミングで削除したのかがわかりません。
SourceTreeで「定数名」で検索をしようとしていますが、やり方がわかりません。

コミットメッセージの検索、ファイルの変更の検索、作者の検索はあります。
しかしながら、ソース、コードの検索は無いように思えます。

なにか良い方法はあるでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 対象のファイルが分かっていれば確認もある程度簡単ですが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルの目安はついています！定義もいつくかに分けて書いてしまっているのですが、多くても3ファイルです。